# Migration from WAS to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

We are in process of migrating our application from WAS to tomcat. Although setup is ready, we are having trouble connecting to our queue manager. In mq jms trace, we could see following exception.

```
    14:49:35.205.02  0001  @6c3ee210  c.i.m.jmqi.system.JmqiSystemEnvironment(JmqiEnvironment)               ---  d  getInstance(String,int) Caught expected exception at catch index 8 [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8568: The native JNI library 'mqjbnd' was not found. [3=mqjbnd]]
    
                     ----+--  {  <init>(String,String,String,String,Map) [JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.] [JMSFMQ6312] [The Java(tm) MQI has thrown an exception describing the problem. ] [See the linked exception for further information.] <null>
    
    Resource name="jms/MQConnectionFactory" auth="Container" type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory" factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory"
              HOST="hostnamename" PORT="port" CHAN="channel" TRAN="1" SCPHS="Cipher" QMGR="queue manager" />

In tomcat/lib, we have below jar 

fscontext.jar
jms.jar
JSON4J.jar
providerutil.jar
com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar
com.ibm.mq.traceControl.jar
```

In context.xml we have specify transport type as client, so it should be looking for native libraries.

Not sure which configuration is missing

Comment: It _should be looking for native libraries_ you say. The log says that it apparently indeed is looking: "The native JNI library 'mqjbnd' was not found."

Comment: But I have specified client mode not binding mode.

Comment: Sorry, if transport type is client, it shouldn't look for native libraries

Comment: Are you sure that it shouldn't be looking, or that they're just not needed (but still might be loaded)? (also: You can/should edit your question with this correction) - and on that topic I'm out. My comment above was just pointing to the obvious, low hanging fruit.